# Calling function on function result like jQuery does

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am trying to build two functions to work like jQuery functions work, for example: jQuery( 'select').val();

This works:

```
function func(a) {
    console.log(1);
    return a;
}

func.sub = function(n) {
    console.log(2);
}

func.sub(2);
```

But this doesn't:

```
function func(a) {
    console.log(1);
    return a;
}

func.sub = function(n) {
    console.log(2);
    //return func result[n];
}

func([1,2,3]).sub(2);
```

How can I make this second code work and read func() result on sub()?

Comment: array will be returned from function `func`

Comment: I know, im asking how to do it the right way so it would work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have `func` return an object that has a method `sub`.

```
function Subbable(x) {
  this.value = x;
}
Subbable.prototype.sub = function(b) {
  return this.value - b;
}

function func(a) {
  return new Subbable(a);
}

func(10).sub(2)
// 8
```

jQuery's `$(...)` typically returns a jQuery object that contains a collection of the selected nodes, and whose prototype has all the nice goodies like `.attr` and `.css`.